# The script lists the names of relational tables created in your account

Tags: sql, database, oracle

how to write the  script to  lists the names of relational tables created in your account and the total number of columns in each table. The names of relational tables must be listed in the descending order of the total number of columns.

For oracle server

Comment: which SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Be specified to question: which server you are using, what language you're using.

On general, with python in mysql server, If you want to show all the database on your server (localhost or other) use the script below and for tables you can use `cursor.execute("show tables")` command.

```
import mysql.connector
database=mysql.connector.connect(host="<hostname>",user="<username>",passwd="<password>", port="<port no of database>")
cursor=database.cursor()
cursor.execute("show databases")
for db in cursor:
   print(db)
```